# Referencing python package name without hard coding its name

Tags: python, package

So I have a python package which contains a number of .py files in it.

```
my_python_package
         |
         |________ __init__.py
         |________ quickstart.py
```

In my quickstart.py file, I want to reference my_python_package; which I can obviously do so by writing

```
import my_python_package
```

Is there a better way I can reference `my_python_package` without explicitly importing it by name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can reference things inside the package using relative imports with the dot syntax, e.g.

```
from . import someOtherModule
from . import SomeClass
```

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for as I am just interested to reference my package name, inside one of that package's own .py file. Without having to use its name if possible.

Comment: @CalvinCheng: There is no standard way to do that.  You might be able to hack something up but it would be fragile.  Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I don't strictly need it. I was just wondering if it is possible. Problem solved then. Thanks!